# What could be the reason for error " fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,ip,port:9092)] failed"

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which read the data from Kafka( broker A) and topic (topic A),After processing then I am sending to another kafka broker(broker B) and Topic (Topic B) and also the same message sending mqtt broker. Job runs for some time around 1 hour, after that I am getting below error.

```
17/07/12 17:47:22 ERROR Utils$: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$1.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
        at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:67)
        at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
        at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
        at com.test.spark.streaming.JobKafka$3$1.call(JobKafka.java:194)
        at com.test.spark.streaming.JobKafka$3$1.call(JobKafka.java:167)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2021)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2021)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        ... 20 more
17/07/12 17:47:22 ERROR DefaultEventHandler: Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
17/07/12 17:47:22 ERROR Utils$: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
        at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
        at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
        at com.test.spark.streaming.JobKafka$3$1.call(JobKafka.java:194)
        at com.test.spark.streaming.JobKafka$3$1.call(JobKafka.java:167)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2021)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2021)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        ... 20 more
17/07/12 17:47:22 ERROR DefaultEventHandler: Failed to collate messages by topic, partition due to: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
17/07/12 17:47:22 ERROR Utils$: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
kafka.common.KafkaException: fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(topicname)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,port:9092)] failed
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.BrokerPartitionInfo.updateInfo(BrokerPartitionInfo.scala:82)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler$$anonfun$handle$2.apply$mcV$sp(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallow(Utils.scala:172)
        at kafka.utils.Logging$class.swallowError(Logging.scala:106)
        at kafka.utils.Utils$.swallowError(Utils.scala:45)
        at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:78)
        at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
        at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
        at com.test.spark.streaming.JobKafka$3$1.call(JobKafka.java:194)
        at com.test.spark.streaming.JobKafka$3$1.call(JobKafka.java:167)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreachPartitionAsync$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:741)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2021)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$34.apply(SparkContext.scala:2021)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.liftedTree1$1(SyncProducer.scala:73)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.kafka$producer$SyncProducer$$doSend(SyncProducer.scala:72)
        at kafka.producer.SyncProducer.send(SyncProducer.scala:113)
        at kafka.client.ClientUtils$.fetchTopicMetadata(ClientUtils.scala:58)
        ... 20 more
```

Below is the sample code

```
 basicGpsData.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<GpsData>>() {


        @Override
        public void call(JavaRDD<GpsData> rdd) throws Exception {



            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("metadata.broker.list",kafkatotopics);
            properties.put("serializer.class","kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");

            rdd.foreachPartitionAsync(new VoidFunction<Iterator<GpsData>>() {
                ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                @Override
                public void call(Iterator<GpsData> partitionRdd) throws Exception {
                    MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();
                    MqttClient client = new MqttClient(mqttbroker, MqttClient.generateClientId(), persistence);


                    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
                    options.setMaxInflight(1000);
                    client.connect(options);

                    ProducerConfig producerConfig = new ProducerConfig(properties);
                    kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String,String> producer = new kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer<String, String>(producerConfig);
                    while(partitionRdd.hasNext()){
                        GpsData gpsData = partitionRdd.next();
                        String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(gpsData);
                        System.out.println(" The data is sending to kafka : "+json);
                        // to send to the kafka
                        KeyedMessage<String, String> kafkaMessage =new KeyedMessage<String, String>(totopics,json);
                        producer.send(kafkaMessage);
                        System.out.println(" The data is sending to MQTT Broker : "+json);
                        MqttTopic msgtopic = client.getTopic(mqtttopic+gpsData.getImei());
                        MqttMessage mqttMessage = new MqttMessage();
                        mqttMessage.setPayload(json.getBytes());
                        msgtopic.publish(mqttMessage);

                    }
                    client.disconnect();

                }
            });

        }
    });
```

getting the below error after 1 hour.

Comment: Can you see anything in your Kafka logs when this happens? With a ClosedChannelException I'd first think of some network connectivity issue between your producers and the brokers.

Comment: I checked Kafka logs, there is no any error/warn thrown at that time,If restart the spark job again it will start normally for another 1-2 hours.I feel there is no network issue.

Comment: Is the error you have pasted above shown repeatedly in the logs or does it occur just once and then the job stops? If it is shown repeatedly it might be a good thing to run a "tcpdump -n 'port 9092' " on the brokers to ensure that a connection attempt actually takes place and reaches that system.

Comment: Thanks for your interest, The error above posted is shown just once and job got stops.